# fail to install electron in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I followed the command `'npm install -g electron'`, the command line gives me back an error `'EACCES:permission denied, mkdir /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/.electron'`

I tried to give permission by '`chown -R root /usr/local/lib/node_modules/*`', but still doen't work?

anyone seen the problem before?

---

solved:
at last I found you can install it directly without root or sudo

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`. As you are installing electron in global scope, you may need to give sudo access... try `sudo npm install -g electron`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `-g` flag for global, you have to either run the command as the `root` user or invoke the command with `sudo`

`sudo npm install -g electron`

Comment: i did use both sudo and root, but still faced the problem

Comment: You can try the following: `sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`